# Spatial reference conflict: WGS84 or clrk66

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, proj, datum

For a raster dataset, trying `my.raster@crs` or `proj4string(my.raster)` in R gives the PROJ.4 string `"+proj=longlat +ellps=clrk66 +no_defs"`. I downloaded the raster from SEDAC [here](http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/wildareas-v2-human-influence-index-geographic/data-download) - the World link, unprojected (geographic). However, on the [metadata link - Spatial Reference](http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/wildareas-v2-human-influence-index-geographic/metadata#Spatial_Reference_Information) it is declared that the ellipsoid and datum are `WGS84`. However, the PROJ.4 string indicates the ellipsoid `clrk66` and no information about the datum. Moreover, in the help file of `spTransform-methods {rgdal}`, Roger Bivand mentions that:

> In general +datum= is to be prefered to +ellps=, because the datum always fixes the ellipsoid, but the ellipsoid never fixes the datum.

So, given this situation what datum can I assume? Can I assume a `WGS84` both for datum and ellipsoid as in the online metadata? I also asked for feedback on the SEDAC's page [here](https://sedac.uservoice.com/forums/110425-feedback/suggestions/20453275-spatial-reference-for-global-human-footprint-glo), but maybe some of you can help me understand this issue. I also saw a combination of `+ellps=clrk66 +datum=NAD27` (`epsg:4267`) presented [here](https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/~frazier/RSpatialGuides/OverviewCoordinateReferenceSystems.pdf) or [here](https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%2Bellps%3Dclrk66%20%2Bdatum%3D&type=), so maybe should I assume `datum=NAD27`?

Comment: [EPSG 4008](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/unknown-datum-based-upon-the-clarke-1866-ellipsoid/) doesn't specify datum. If online metadata says that is in WGS 84, you can try adding world's boundaries in WGS 84 and NAD 27 and judge yourself (but I think there will not be significative differences)

Comment: Hi @aldo_tapia! This lack of datum is really confusing in EPSG 4008. I am curious how can I even make a datum transformation when there is no datum? For example, the tool `Project` from  ArcMap will not let me transform without a [datum transformation](http://downloads2.esri.com/support/TechArticles/geographic_transformations_1031.pdf).

Comment: Yes, but you can follow online metada and set CRS to [EPSG 4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/). For global scale, is weird to see data in NAD 27, is more common to see it in WGS 84

Comment: Entries like EPSG::4008 were added for use when people know the ellipsoid, but not the datum. Older maps sometimes would have the ellipsoid but not other information. Sometimes you can guess the datum; sometimes there may have been 2 different datums using same ellipsoid in the area.

Comment: Ah, it says the rasters are in ArcInfo GRID format. If there's no prj.adf present or there is but no datum inf\ormation, the default ellipsoid is Clarke 1866.

Comment: Hi @mkennedy! I saw you also answered this related [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59377/define-a-datum-and-meridian-in-a-crs-in-qgis/59410). The feedback from SEDAC is: "the spatial reference datum is Clarke 1866". I thought it might be NAD27. Is it valid to use now `+proj=longlat +ellps=clrk66 +datum=clrk66 +no_defs`? I saw that ArcMap reads _GCS_Clarke_1866 WKID: 4008 Authority: EPSG_ as you and @aldo_tapia commented about.

Comment: If you use 4008, you're not going to be able to use any geographic/datum transformations to convert to WGS84 or anything else. The data has a 1km resolution. Just set it to WGS84 (4326). The offsets between older datums and newer ones are anywhere from tens of meters to a few hundred m. All are less than the data resolution.